# Can we take the value of iterator which was returned from lower_bound as vector index?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm new to vector in C++ and trying to get how it works.
First, I have a vector array:

```
vector<int>container;
```

Then I want to get the position of a given number in a vector array.

```
vector<int>::iterator position;
    position = lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), temp);
```

After that, I want to get the value at that position that was returned from `lower_bound` by

```
container[position]
```

But I get the error that

> No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector'

When I change it into `*(position+1)`, it works fine.
So what is the different between those two?

Comment: You dont need to do `container[position]`, you can just use `*position` to get the value the iterator points to.  You also need to check that `position != container.end()` before doing that

Comment: @NathanOliver Can I ask why should I add `position != container.end()` before getting the position?

Comment: because if no element is found, the end iterator is returned and that does not point to a valid element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we should understand what an iterator is. According to the [`hackingcpp`](https://hackingcpp.com/cpp/std/iterators_intro.html)

> - objects that point to a location
> - may point to a readable memory address / object
> - ..

There are a lot of containers in C++ STL, such as `vector`, `list`, `map` and others.

A iterator is an **abstraction** of pointer, which allows you to access elements stored in container, use algorithm(such as `sort`, `find`, `lower_bound`) provided by STL no matter what kind of container we have.

Therefore, the return type of `std::lower_bound` is an iterator as you know `vector<int>::iterator`,

You couldn't access an element by calling `container[position]`, there is no such function `vector[iterator]` provided by vector.

> When I change it into *(position+1)

`*itreator` means return the value of where an iterator points out.

By the way, it's dangerous to do something like this `*(position+1)`.

Since perhaps the given value `tmp` is in `vector`, perhaps it's not, so you should check whether the given value `tmp` is in `vector` by calling `iterator != vector.end()`.

Comment: A pair of iterators designates a **sequence**. Containers are one way of managing sequences, but they are not the only way. For example, the characters read from `std::cin` form a sequence that can be accessed through various flavors of `std::istream_iterator`. So, while it's correct that iterators "[allow] you to access elements stored in [a] container", they can do much more than that. +1.

Comment: Note, also, that `position+1` is only valid for random access iterators. Less powerful iterators don't support addition.

Comment: Pete's supplement is a great point, there are different kinds of iterators provided by the standard library for different purpose: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/. By the way, in C++20, we call the `sequence` as `range`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::lower_bound` returns a `ForwardIterator` (See: [C++ named requirements: LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)).
You can dereference it just like you would a pointer, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<int> container;
// ...
auto it = std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), foo);
if (container.end() == it) { 
  throw or_something("handle error?");
}
const int x = *it;
const int y = container[std::distance(container.begin(), it)];
```

In that example `x == y` is `true`. (See: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/f8eareq5v))